# How can I create this simple view?

Tags: sql, oracle

Source:

```
LAN COD     DESC
C   1234    Description in spanish 
V   1234    Description in english 
C   1235    Description in spanish  
V   1235    Description in english   
C   1236    Description in spanish      
V   1236    Description in english
```

Created View:

COD, DESC in spanish, DESC in english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select cod,
       max(case when language = 'C' then description end),
       max(case when language = 'V' then description end)
from t
group by cod;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
PIVOT (
  MAX( descr )
  FOR lan IN (
    'C' AS Spanish,
    'V' AS English
  )
)
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( LAN, COD, DESCR ) AS
SELECT 'C', 1234, 'Description in spanish' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'V', 1234, 'Description in english' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 1235, 'Description in spanish' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'V', 1235, 'Description in english' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 1236, 'Description in spanish' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'V', 1236, 'Description in english' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
>  COD | SPANISH                | ENGLISH               
> ---: | :--------------------- | :---------------------
> 1234 | Description in spanish | Description in english
> 1236 | Description in spanish | Description in english
> 1235 | Description in spanish | Description in english
> ```

If you want it as a `VIEW` then:

```sql
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
PIVOT (
  MAX( descr )
  FOR lan IN (
    'C' AS Spanish,
    'V' AS English
  )
)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f05ece075bbc2aafe3bd922ffa3060e4)*

Comment: It's a bit tricky, but very effective.
What if you need fields from more tables? In a specific order? The "PIVOT" would not serve as much?

Comment: @AntonioDelicadoLópez `PIVOT` is very simple and you can change `SELECT *` to name the columns (i.e. `SELECT cod, english, spanish`) and then you can add them in whatever order you want. If you need more fields from more table then just `JOIN` them (either before or after `PIVOT`ing as you require).